ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) - MariaDb on Docker
I have browsed all of the available threads regarding this issue but none of them seem to help solving my problem.
Having pulled my mariadb image with command (on root account using su):
docker pull mariadb:latest
Then running:
docker run -d --name some_name -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=some_secret_password -p 1111:3306 -v /volume/path:/volume/path mariadb:latest
Then doing (after this command i get root@some_numbers in prompt so i assume im in root mode):
docker exec -it some_name bash
Then changing in 50-server.cnf following line:
bind_address 172.0.0.1 -> bind_address 0.0.0.0 to supposedly accept all traffic not only from localhost
Then trying to login for the first time:
mariadb -P 1111 --protocol=tcp -u root -p yes, i know about -p to write password like this -pPASSWORD etc. it does not work, also when leaving empty it does not work, not any variant of this command works, all of the proper ones give one, and same result:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'some_ip' (using password: YES)
And i have tried it from docker container with root privileges (su mode on), on host machine with root privileges and on remote machine with root privileges all with the same result shown above. I also am aware of this one: link and I am surprised that when being literaly on root account with su mode on I still can not log in.
I also can not do anything to mariadb service to shut it down and restart with skip grant flag as shown here: link
To summarize, I want to get an access to mariadb instance that sits in container on remote server based on ubuntu to access it with another remote machine in the future, but for now after following every step I could find, I am stuck at a simple log in for the first time into database.

I've tried your example with both a mariadb 10.5 and 11.6 client and both connect using your described execution.
e.g:
$ client/mariadb -P 1111 --protocol=tcp -u root -psome_secret_password
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 4
Server version: 11.4.2-MariaDB-ubu2404 mariadb.org binary distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> \s
--------------
client/mariadb from 11.6.0-MariaDB, client 15.2 for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Connection id:      4
Current database:   
Current user:       root@::1
SSL:            Cipher in use is TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, cert is OK
Current pager:      stdout
Using outfile:      ''
Using delimiter:    ;
Server:         MariaDB
Server version:     11.4.2-MariaDB-ubu2404 mariadb.org binary distribution
Protocol version:   10
Connection:     localhost via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    utf8mb4
Db     characterset:    utf8mb4
Client characterset:    utf8mb3
Conn.  characterset:    utf8mb3
TCP port:       1111
Uptime:         2 min 48 sec


The issue is MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=some_secret_password or more modernly MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=some_secret_password is not used after the data volume /volume/path is initialized. Whatever the password was when the volume was created its not currently some_secret_password (or whatever it really was).
It also might be the case that if your some_secret_password contains characters with shell meanings then those may change what is passed though to the MariaDB server. Quote if unsure like '-psome_secret_password'. For a long time the MariaDB container has been able to handle any password.
If you are still stuck, reset the password with:
docker run -d --name some_name -p 1111:3306 -v /volume/path:/volume/path mariadb:latest --skip-grant-tables
mariadb -P 1111 --protocol=tcp -u root -e 'flush privileges;set password=password=("some_other_secret_password")'


Does Your solution apply still if I have tried echo $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD and it did show me some_secret_password?

MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD is just what's in the container runtime. It isn't persistent like the data volume. So yes, still applies.

I would like to mark this as the best answer, because seeing You doing exactly the same as me helped me to retake all the steps for the fifth time checking everything and what was the problem? Apparently while creating password and using special characters there was a difference in sign produced using the same key combination to obtain it - thus passwords realy did not match. Thanks.
